# If $‎{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n) - f(n+1)) = 0‎$, then $‎{\lim_{x\to\infty}}f(x) = L‎$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convex-analysis

‎Let ‎$‎f:[1,+‎\infty‎)‎‎\rightarrow‎‎\mathbb{R}‎$ ‎be a ‎‎concave‎ ‎function ‎such ‎that‎ $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n) - f(n+1)) = 0‎$ ( $‎n‎$ is positive integer‎‎‎)‎‎. My question is :‎

‎
‎‎‎What other condition is required ‏‎that $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}f(x) = L‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎?‎

‎
 I know that ‎i‎f ‎‎$‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎f(x) = L‎$, ‎then‎ ‎‎$‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}‎f(n)= L‎$. Therefore ‎ $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n) - f(n+1)) = 0‎$.

‎And also, if $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}f(n) = L‎$ ‎and ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is monotone, then $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}f(x) = L‎$. But‎
$‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n) - f(n+1)) = 0‎ ‎‎‎\nRightarrow‎‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}f(n) = L‎$.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, take $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ or $f(x)=\log(x)$ or $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} \frac{1}{k}$. All of these functions satisfy $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(f(n)-f(n+1)\bigg)=0$ but they get infinitely large when $x$ approaches infinity. There's a thread about this that was active just yesterday.

Comment: stressed out. Exactly. Now I want to apply a condition that $‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}f(x) = L‎$.

Comment: I think there are some easy remedies. For example, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(f(n)-f(n+m)\bigg)=0$ for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\{f(n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ will become a Cauchy sequence. Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L$ and since $f$ is monotone, I think it can be proven that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ too. Another possible remedy is to make $f$ bounded above/below.

Comment: stressed out. How can ‎I‎ prove ‎if $‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n) - f(n+m)‎) =‎ ‎0‎$ ‎for any ‎‎$‎m\in‎\mathbb{N}‎‎$‎, then ‎‎$‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}f(n) = L‎$?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. My previous satement has been worded incorrectly. I think It has to be $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty} \big( f(n)-f(n+m) \big) = 0$ to imply that $\{f(n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy. After you've proven that it's Cauchy, since $\{f(n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, it should converge to some real number $L$.

Comment: stressed out.Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I just checked rigorously that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty} \big( f(n)-f(n+m) \big) = 0$ does indeed imply that $\{f(n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy. So, we can be sure that it's not incorrect this time. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concavity is important here. That $f$ is concave means that $f$ is at or above any chord. That is, on any interval $[a,b]$, $$f(x) \ge \frac{f(a)(b - x) + (x-a)f(b)}{b - a}$$ In particular, $f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right) \ge \frac{f(a)+f(b)}2$. If we apply this to $a = n, b = n+2$, we get $$2f(n+1) \ge f(n) + f(n+2)\\f(n+1) - f(n+2) \ge f(n) - f(n+1)$$ By induction, if $n\ge m$,
$$f(n) - f(n+1) \ge f(m) - f(m+1)$$

If for some $m, f(m) - f(m+1) = \epsilon > 0$, then for all $n > m, f(n)-f(n+1) \ge \epsilon$ as well, contradicting that $\lim_n f(n) - f(n+1) = 0$. That is, $f$ must be increasing (or at least constant) on the integers.

Now let $n > x_2 > x_1$ for some integer $n$ and real numbers $x_2, x_1$. We know that $f(n+1) \ge f(n)$. If $f(x_1) > f(n)$, then $f(n)$ would be below the line connecting $(x_1,f(x_1))$ to $(n+1,f(n+1))$, which cannot be. Therefore $f(x_1) \le f(n)$. If $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$, then $f(x_2)$ would be below the line connecting $(x_1,f(x_1)$ to $(n,f(n))$, which also cannot be. Therefore we can conclude that $f(x_2) \ge f(x_1)$. I.e., $f$ must be increasing.

And there you have it. Since $f$ is increasing, it has a limit if and only it is bounded above. Boundedness is the condition you are after.

Similarly, if you replace "concave" with "convex", $f$ will be decreasing, and have a limit if and only if it is bounded below.

Answer (score 1):

if a function has limit, it is bounded, and the condition of $sup(-f(x))=-inff(x)$ and $inf(-f(x))=-supf(x)$ correspond respectively to convex and concave function.

however, if a monotone function satisfy both these two conditions, it will behave like a wave and turbulence around its domain, in this case, this function do not have limit!

thank you!